# Show related products in the same category - Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I need to show in the related products block a list of products of the same category in the product page.

For example:

I have a pink candle product and I want to show in the related products block automatically 4 random products of the same category (candles).

Is it possible or do I need to manually select the related or upsell products?

I'm using Magento v1.9.3 and Gala Themes' Supermarket & Deal theme.

Comment: You may be able to achieve it via `$relatedProductsBlock->getItems()->addCategoryFilter(Mage::registry('current_category'))` before `echo $relatedProductsBlock->toHtml()`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?